# Rationale for order of arguments to `get` function

Tags: elm

Why are the arguments ordered the way they are in `Array.get` and `Dict.get`? The order in most map/filter functions makes sense: the function comes before the collection (or monad, more generally).

```
MyCollection.map : (a -> b) -> MyCollection a -> MyCollection b
```

This makes it easier to compose higher functions out of smaller ones before passing in a collection.

Why, however, does the index/key come before the collection in get functions?

```
Dict.get : comparable -> Dict comparable v -> Maybe v
```

It seems to make it harder to compose higher functions. If the arguments were reversed, one could write:

```
ids : List Int
myObjects : Dict Int a

selectObjects = List.map (Dict.get myObjects) ids
```

But instead, the best way I can come up with to write this is:

```
ids : List Int
myObjects : Dict Int a

selectObjects = List.map (\id -> (Dict.get id myObjects)) ids
```

Am I missing something? What is the reason for the argument order in `Array.get`, `Dict.get`, and similar?

Comment: You could use [`flip`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Basics#flip) to get rid of the lambda: `List.map (flip Dict.get myObjects) ids`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I wasn't asking how to work around this, which is quite easy. I'd like to know the reasoning behind the argument order, since I'm not very experienced with FP and I'd like to know if there's some benefit the library design allows.

Comment: My guess is that it was designed to look like Haskell's [`Data.Map.lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:lookup) function which, coincidentally, is listed under the [bad examples](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parameter_order#Bad_examples) section of parameter ordering on the Haskell wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.map (Dict.get myObjects) ids` isn't function composition.

Composition is when you have
`f : X -> Y` and
`g : Y -> Z` then you *compose* them
`h = f >> g` so that
`h : X -> Z`

Now, when composing functions as above, we need them to require ONLY one more parameter.

So when defining an API, the question is:
"When someone partially evaluates this function so that it can be composed, what is the last parameter they'll *likely* want to pass it?"

In other words, are we more likely to see code like:
`getStuff >> mungeIntoDict >> (Dict.get id)`
or
`getStuff >> getImportantId >> (Dict.get myDict)`
?

The answer to that is "it depends". The API designers took their best guess and we have `flip` for when it doesn't suit us.